Unable to get l2tp 1.3.16 to work on Ubuntu 22.04
System details:
Laptop: TIMI Mi NoteBook Ultra
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Processor: 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-11320H @ 3.20GHz × 8
xl2tpd version: xl2tpd-1.3.16
I have been trying to set up l2tp on my machine to connect to the VPN. However, after installing and setting up the VPN profile when I try to connect to the VPN I always get an "Activation of network connection failed" notification. The same VPN profile is working on another system but that has Ubuntu 20 and the xl2tpd version is 1.3.12.
Following things I have tried that have not worked:

Downgrading xl2tpd on my machine to 1.3.12
Finding out how to debug the problem which led me to

tail -f /var/log/syslog command. When I run this and try to connect to the VPN, the error message on the terminal is
 NetworkManager[8444]: 003 "a1b5319f-4df2-4a93-b051-d003158ebe03" #1: we require the IKEv1 peer to have ID 'yyy', but peer declares 'xxx'.

I believe this must have some clue to the underlying issue. I checked this error message online, and found out, that it could mean either the local machine or the remote machine is misconfigured. Chances of the remote machine being set up wrong are minimal as other team members using the same config can connect to VPN so something must be wrong on my machine.
I am a bit new to this so some of the similar questions on this site make little sense to me.

I have migrated this from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78273527/unable-to-get-l2tp-1-3-16-to-work-on-ubuntu-22-04
